# program lagging terribly despite using 1% of CPU and only 134m of ram, any assistance would be great

Tags: interface

just installed blender onto my laptop, was working just fine on my ancient crippled pc yet now the whole program lags to an unusable degree, it takes five seconds to even open the file menu and the 3d navigation window is nearly unusable.

has anyone else had a similar issue and found a solution? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my laptop until I installed the latest drivers for my GPU and set the Nvidia Control Panel to use the dedicated GPU for Blender.